# Button background alignment

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm a long-time web dev trying to get into iOS development and Xcode so please forgive me for the simplest of questions.

I have a strange issue when I cannot centre align button text within a button's background image. Please see the screenshot below. At the moment you can see the text sits right aligned to the background image.

[image]

Comment: Look into "constraints" it doesn't seem like you are using any

Comment: *"I cannot centre align button text within a button's background image"* -- it's not clear what you **want** to do... is it one of these three layouts? https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtX5s.png

Answer (score 0):

It’s not a background image. Think of it more like an icon.

It looks like you might want to set your Style to “Default”. Then it will show a background field under image